Visual Studio (64-bit) V17.11.5 (.NET V4.8.09032) 100% Scaling bug?
My PC has a 4k monitor with the graphics card resolution at 3840 x 2160 with a 150% scale (via windows 11 Home).
When I click on an .sln file to load a project:
VS Launches.
If a form (design) is not already showing (edit mode) and I click open (show) a form to edit and then I click on "Restart VS with 100% scaling", it restarts and I get a weird 'garbage' solution.
But, if a Form (design) is already showing and I click on "Restart VS with 100% scaling", it restarts and I get my normal solution.
I don't know if this just started latest or not.
Can anyone else duplicate this problem?
My workaround is to have a Form (Design) showing when I close VS.

I think for this question, a screenshot of the 'garbage' solution would help.

I imported a screenshot when I submitted the question.  What happened to it?

Apparently I don't have enough reputation points to post a screenshot because I'm a new poster.  So I will try to describe the garbage solution: It has no tools to show in the Toolbox.  The solution name (shown at top middle of VS) simply says "17.0_00d9af28".  The Solution Explorer does not have any of my Forms or Classes listed, just a bunch of 'system?' sub-folders under the top folder name of  '17.0_00d9af28(C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\17.0_00d9af28'

Could you please let me know where you saw the "Restart Visual Studio with 100% scaling" option? And If you do not select this setting, will these types of issues occur when opening Visual Studio normally?

@Zhenning Zhang - the 'Restart Visual Studio with 100% scaling' appears near the top of visual studio as a yellow banner just under the 'Form1.cs [Design]' tab when you click on the form1 to edit.

Good day, I'm glad you've found a way to fix this problem . If possible, please post an answer so that others who encounter similar issues can see the solution

I found out that this problem was reported to Microsoft a few months ago. They said that it had been fixed in the latest version of Visual Studio. I already had the latest update, but it still did not fix it. So I deleted VS, cleaned my registry, rebooted my computer, downloaded/reinstalled VS (same version) and now the problem is gone. So having the latest update might not fix it. Delete, clean registry and reinstall VS was my solution

I doubt that cleaning the registry had anything to do with the fix. As for the VS reinstall, sadly that is sometimes called for. Glad it worked. Maybe in another decade, Visual Studio will be half as stable as Rider.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
